# Ruby on rails - how to join 4 tables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

This is what I have:

```
class Membership < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :group
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :user_score
  has_many :memberships
  has_and_belongs_to_many :groups, through: :memberships # an user can be owner or member of a group
end

class Group < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :members, through: :memberships, source: :user
end

class UserScore < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

What I'm trying to do is to get a list of users from a group ordered by 'total_score' (which is an attribute of UserScore) but I've failing so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously, I do not have the schema loaded on my machine. So, my answer will be something like

```
User.joins(:user_score, :groups).where(groups: {name: 'Name of your group'}).order('user_scores.total_score')
```